# Как правильно передать текст из EditText между двумя фрагментами

Tags: java, android

Главный экран разделен на 2 части, по одной для каждого фрагмента.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_fragment1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fragments.Fragment1" >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1F1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1F1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1F1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Такой же xml и для второго фрагмента, только id элементов отличаются.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentEventListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.container1).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        findViewById(R.id.container2).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        try {
            Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
            Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container1, f1);
            ft.replace(R.id.container2, f2);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "False", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setFragmentTextViewText(int idTextView,
            String text) {

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(idTextView);
        tv.setText(text);

    }

    @Override
    public void showToast(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**FragmentEventListener.java**

```
package com.example.fragments;

public interface FragmentEventListener {
    void setFragmentTextViewText(int idTextView, String text);

    void showToast(String text);
}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, null);
        EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1F1);
        final String str = et.getText().toString();
        v.findViewById(R.id.btn1F1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragmentEventListener listener = (FragmentEventListener) getActivity();
                listener.setFragmentTextViewText(R.id.tv1F2, str);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, null);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btn1F2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentEventListener listener = (FragmentEventListener) getActivity();
                EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1F2);
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                listener.setFragmentTextViewText(R.id.tv1F1, str);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

Идея такая - при запуске вижу 2 фрагмента. Ввожу текст в EditText первого фрагмента, нажимаю кнопку и TextView второго фрагмента меняется на введенный. Мой код крашится на моменте

```
EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1F2);
String str = et.getText().toString();
```

Но в фрагмент 1 я вставил его в onCreateView, перед обработчиков клика, и в результате вообще ничего не происходит.

А в фрагменте 2 я вставил его в onClick, и в этом случае программа закрывается с ошибкой.

Comment: и правильно крашится - для фрагмента подтянулся свой файл разметки, и вы пытаетесь в view фрагмента найти кусок другого view...
Подскажу куда копать - активность имеет доступ к обоим фрагментам в вашем случае...

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky погодите, я ведь не пытаюсь из view фрагмента1 обратиться к EditText, что находится во View фрагмента2. 
Я наоборот в фрагменте1 нахожу свой EditText, который там находится! и ошибки на этой строке нет. Ошибка в строке когда я уже текст с него вытаскиваю. str = et.getText().toString();

Comment: точно, не заметил, а случайно ошибка не NullPointerException?

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky а как узнать?

Comment: в AndroidStudio открыть вкладку снизу Android Monitor, выбрать тип Error и посмотреть стек ошибок.
Есть подозрение что строку: EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1F2); надо вынести из onClick в onCreateView

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky просто я в эклипсе работаю. Там немного подругому но ошибку вроде не пишет. И я пытался вынести эти строки из OnClick, в этом случает отправляется пустая строка. 

Еще пробовал просто сделать это в MainActivity, там вообще проблем нет, все работает. Но это ведь неправильно так делать. За то что творится в фрагменте1 должен отвечать Fragment1.java...

Comment: все верно, но за обмен между фрагментами отвечает их активность, чуть позже попробую у себя ваш код запустить и посмотреть что происходит.

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

корректный код фрагмента (они идентичны - только имена поменять и id поправить)

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

private String str;

public Fragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, null);
    final EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1F2);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn1F2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            str = et.getText().toString();
            FragmentEventListener listener = (FragmentEventListener) getActivity();
            listener.setFragmentTextViewText(R.id.tv1F1, str);
        }
    });
    return v;
    }

}
```