# Передача данных между Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть Activity с BottomNavigationView. С помощью последнего я переключаю фрагменты. Мне нужно передать ArrayList моих классов между этими двумя фрагментами. Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это сделать.
Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
    TranslatorFragment translatorFragment = TranslatorFragment.newInstance();
    HistoryFragment historyFragment = HistoryFragment.newInstance();

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_translator:
                    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayoutMain,translatorFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_history:
                    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayoutMain, historyFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayoutMain,TranslatorFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#696969")));

    }
}
```

Comment: Обмен данными между фрагментами размещенными на одной Activity должна осуществлять Activity посредством интерфейса. пример: https://metanit.com/java/android/8.5.php и совсем недавно этот вопрос подымался: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671948/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-edittext-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/672074#672074

Comment: я скоро начну минусовать за такие вопросы - такое ощущение, что народ не читает документацию и вообще не включает мозги.